# How to filter gridview records faster way?

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview which contains 100 records i have set paging to 10. At page_load it fills the grid so the records are not going to change so i dont need to hit to database again. 
There is a filter textbox availble at the top of 'Name' Column when user types some key it should filter the 100 records & should return the matched records (e.g using Contains filter).
It is not very difficult task if i user update panel. But, It takes time becoz i am fetching records on each key. Even i use viewstate it slows down the performance. Is there any alternative way to achieve this? I am wondering if u could use some javascript logic

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with implementing server side instead of with javascript, you could store the data in the cache object on first load, and then pull from cache on each subsequent hit.

[A very simple example](http://qureshi-zubair.blogspot.com/2008/03/gridview-with-caching.html)